# C++ where intermediate value store?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction

My question can be pointed out regarding any programming language, but I wanna know regarding C++. I want to know where the intermediate value will store in C++? For example in the below code:

```
int func1(int);
int func2(int);
int func3(int);
int main(){
    int a = 10;
    int b = func1(func2(func3(a)));
    cout<<b<<endl;
}
```

where the return value of ***func3*** will be stored? What about ***func2***? Will it store in CPU cache? or Ram?
Also, regarding the below code where the result of `a*b` will be stored? Or any intermediate values:

```
int main(){
    int a = 10;
    int b = 15;
    int c = a*b+10*15;
    cout<<c<<endl;
}
```

If it is compiler dependent, please explain regarding any compiler, especially GCC.

Comment: It depends on the compiler where to store the temporary(if any). The C++ Standard only specifies its lifetime.

Comment: Take a look: https://godbolt.org/z/nTes8GrKf

Comment: Generally everything the program operates on is stored in registers with registers saved to memory if there aren't enough of them available to complete an operation

Comment: *"If it is compiler dependent, please explain regarding any compiler, especially GCC."* -- so these two specific expressions (different expressions may yield different answers), using gcc? Hmm... still might not be specific enough. Which version? What optimization level? Which architecture? A lot of factors can influence where (and if) a compiler chooses to store a temporary.

Comment: @AlanBirtles So you mean first compilers try to store in registers, if there isn't any free register then they will store in Ram?

Comment: @JaMiT You're right. I asked a general question that depends on a lot of factors. If you know, please explain in an Answer regarding all factors how it will be stored? Or if there are a lot of factors that are hard to explain all of them, then please at least explain in fewer details.

Comment: @SpongeBob *"If you know, please explain in an Answer regarding all factors how it will be stored?"* The question is too broad to be answered on SO. Please be specific. For example, you can chose a single compiler and tag it with your question.

Comment: yes they do, registers are fast so they try to use them as much as possible

Comment: @SpongeBob I know that the answer depends on a lot of factors, but I do not know all the factors, nor do I know exactly how they influence the result. While I do enjoy a lot of useless trivia, these details have not interested me enough to delve into them. I guess I could post an answer saying that the result could be stored in a register, in a CPU cache, in RAM, or nowhere (if it gets optimized out of existence), but that's not really much more information than what is in your question.

Comment: Registers, the stack, other RAM. It depends entirely on the compiler. There is no one rule. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @SpongeBob - The compiler knows math, so in  the second example, the variables will likely not be stored anywhere and the compiler just does `cout<<300<<endl;`. It just has to produce the result, not generate code for all the steps to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only declared the function I will assume they are in separate compilation units. So the compiler has to generate a function call for them. No inlineing or specialization of the functions possible (lookup link time optimization for how that isn't always true).

The way functions are called, arguments are passed and and returned is defined in the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) for the architecture and ABI you are targeting. So this isn't compiler specific as object files from different compilers are supposed to be compatible if they follow the same ABI.

So this governs what happens in each function call taken on it's own. In between the function calls the values can be stored on the stack or in registers but generally compilers try to do the minimal amount of work to get things from where one function returns them to where the next function expects them.

PS: If the compiler sees the definition of the functions then all bets are of. It can do whatever it likes as long as no change is observable by the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

This intermediate values are stored traditionally on the stack, but beware stack may overflow.com :)